# ROS Answers SE migration: c++ or python

Tags: rospy, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently using python to make stuff in ROS, would it be worthwhile to learn cpp? Are there things you can't do with python? Is it easier to program things with c++?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208382/c++-or-python/) by [Mr. CEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/21719/mr.-ceo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2015-05-02

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll add something to @aak2166 answer.

Some library you might want to use are going to be exclusively in Python or in CPP. For example, as far as I know, PCL is only in C++ so if you want to use it, you will have to learn C++.
Smash is only in python.

So it depend as well on your project but knowing both is certainly an advantage since you won't be limited by this.

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2015-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adam Allevato](https://answers.ros.org/users/21561/adam-allevato/) on 2015-05-04**:
There are now PCL bindings for Python.

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2015-05-04**:
Good thing I said as far as I know :). I didn't know that, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regarding performance keep in mind that a lot of C++ library (like OpenCV) can be used in Python without loss of performance since they are not executed by Python interpreter. I made some tests with face detection comparing performance between C++ and Python and I did not find significant differences.

My usual approach is to use Python for small integrations and for proof of concept taking advantage of its simplicity and switch to C++ only if this can results in performance improvements.

---

Originally posted by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) with karma: 497 on 2015-05-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Python is used for some modules that don't need fast speed.  However, python is easier to be used. I think the combination of Python and CPP could lead to more work efficiency.

---

Originally posted by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) with karma: 279 on 2015-05-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2